# не работает position fixed на сафари мобайл для фоновой картинки

Tags: html, css

Здраствуйте, я начинающий web-разработчик! В процессе написания сайта я столкнулся с проблемой, того что на мобильной версии хрома при скроле фоновая картинка .wrapper мерцает. А на мобильной версии сафари не работает фиксирование фоновой картинки.
Пробовал так

```
.wrapper{
    background: url(https://irish-st.ucoz.net/images/background_image1.jpg) center center/cover no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-direction: column;}
```

Пробовал и так

```
.wrapper:before {
    background: url(https://irish-st.ucoz.net/images/background_image1.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;}
```

также пробовал применять для родительского блока .wrapper задавать свойство transform: translate3d(0,0,0); этот вариант, тоже не помогает в сафари, и ломает ещё и в хроме то что работает. Помогите пожалуйста кто может знает как это исправить. Ссылка на сайт:https://irish-st.ucoz.net/

scss:

```
.wrapper:before {
    background: url(https://irish-st.ucoz.net/images/background_image1.jpg) center center / cover no-repeat;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;}
```

html:

```
<body class="body" >
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="container">

                <header class="header">
                    <div class="header__top">
                        <div class="header__box_img">
                            <img class="header__img" src="https://irish-st.ucoz.net/images/top_header_image.PNG">
                        </div>
                        <div class="Text__title_1">
                            @irish_st
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header__bottom">
                        <div class="header__decBlock_L"></div>
                        <div class="header__text Text__paragraph">
                            <p class="Text__paragraph">создатель контента и визуала для</p>
                            <p class="Text__paragraph">личных блогов/брендов/маркетплейсов</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__decBlock_R"></div>
                    </div>
                </header>
                
            </div>
            

        </div>
    <script src="https://irish-st.ucoz.net/js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Данное свойство [не поддерживаеться в Safary](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment) браузере. Ищи альтернативу.